# deserialize using Gson gives "Failed to invoke public okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args"

Tags: java, android, gson, deserialization, okhttp

I am trying to cache some network calls while there is no internet connection so that they can be retried later,

I do this by serializing the okhttp3.Request object using `Gson.toJson(...)`
(and some other info like timestamp etc). and serialization works fine and a have inspected the resulting JSON and all the data is there as expected.

However when I later want to deserialize the json with `Gson.FromJson(...)` it throws an error saying:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public
>   okhttp3.RequestBody() with no args

and I have not been able to figure out how to resolve this error.

Any help will be much appreciated.

[EDIT]
I construct the body as follows:

```
FormBody.Builder body = new FormBody.Builder();
body.add({name}, {value});
body.add({name}, {value});
body.build();
```

Comment: Could you show how exactly you build `RequestBody` and `Request` objects? `RequestBody` is an `abstract class` and there is not way to invoke `constructor` with no args. Probably you need to implement custom serialiser and deserialiser for given type.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured that deserializing the okhttp3.Request object is just not going to work.

Instead I have made a simple structure 'PostBodyHolder' that I build as the request object and then this is what gets cached and when I do actually execute the request I build the okhttp3.Request object from the PostBodyHolder.

```
public class PostBodyHolder {

    /**
     * The params of this body.
     */
    public final List<Param> params = new ArrayList<>();
    /**
     * The URL for this body.
     */
    public String url;

    public PostBodyHolder(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public PostBodyHolder add(@NonNull String name, @NonNull String value) {
        params.add(new Param(name, value));
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Holder for body params.
     */
    public class Param {

        /**
         * The name of the Param
         */
        public String name;
        /**
         * The Value of the Param
         */
        public String value;

        public Param(@NonNull String name, @NonNull String value) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

For any interested here is the Kotlin version

```
class PostBodyHolder(
        /**
         * The URL for this body.
         */
        var url: String) {

    /**
     * The params of this body.
     */
    val params: MutableList<Param> = ArrayList()

    fun add(name: String, value: String): PostBodyHolder {
        params.add(Param(name, value))
        return this
    }

    /**
     * Holder for body params.
     */
    inner class Param(
            /**
             * The name of the Param
             */
            var name: String,
            /**
             * The Value of the Param
             */
            var value: String)
}
```